# How to create a date histogram in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, time, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I want to create a date histogram with opensearch dashboards. The time format of my data is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS`, which I have set under **Stack Management > Advanced Settings > Date Format**. I get an error like this:
[image]

Under **Discover**, I can sort by "date", as it is of type "float". My field "timestamp", by which I would like to sort, is of type "string", and I cannot change this via the API:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]"},"status":400}
```

I'm stuck, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a field for [date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html), the field type should be a date.
Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the field type from Kibana => Stack management.

Here is some solution for your case:

1. Use [Histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html)
2. Set the field type and re-index the data

Here are the steps for the second option.

#Check the mapping old_index = your existing index name

`GET old_index`

#Put the new mapping before reindexing

```
PUT new_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#reindex the data

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

Comment: After reindex complete check the document count and create a new index_pattern (data view) in Kibana => stack management and use that field for histogram aggregation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am more or less bound to using opensearch. Do you know if the histogram aggregation is possible there, too?

Comment: Yes, here is the link for histogram aggregation.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/bucket-agg/#histogram-date_histogram
Also, the above commands will work in Opensearch too. You can go to the Opensearch Dashboard => Dev Tools and write that commands

Comment: It works the way you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to hear it worked.
Btw, did you used histogram aggregation or did you reindex the data ?

Comment: I re-indexed the data. Although a problem I have now is that the timestamp that is supposed to be parsed from the log is being overridden by the timestamp at which the document enters opensearch.

Comment: please open another task for it and ping me I will help you with it. you can use ingest_pipeline for that.

Comment: @Musab_Dogan   I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020349/how-to-parse-timestamp-as-date-in-opensearch