# How to parse timestamp as date in opensearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have some logs like this:

```
2022-12-07 17:22:53,838 [INFO]: {"status_code": 304, "method": "GET", "url": "/backend/some/url", "remote_ip": "rem.ote.ip.add", "response_time": 101.61018371582031} - tornado.access
```

I use an aggregator to parse those logs into the fields `timestamp`, `loglevel`, `status_code` etc. and send them to my opensearch instance. The problem is that the timestamp field is of type string in opensearch, so it cannot be sorted by in the **Discover** page. Oddly enough, it also has a field `date` of type `float`.

I then tried creating a new index with a changed timestamp format as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996722/11347405) (second option).

The problem here is that opensearch either uses the date it received the logs as the timestamp, or it just doesn't recognize any timestamp field:

[image]

Comment: @Musab Dogan   ping

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this solution, the `timestamp` field type should be the date.

Can you share the mapping of the index?

```
GET index_name
```

Can you check the index_pattern and make sure the log-9 index_pattern date is set to `timestamp`

Comment: Do you know about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021947/wrong-timestamp-displayed-in-opensearch-dashboards