# Wrong timestamp displayed in Opensearch dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, time, kibana, opensearch

I am trying to add some documents to my opensearch instance with the Python client SDK like so:

```
import opensearchpy

host = 'my_remote_host.com'
port = 9200
auth = ('admin', 'admin')

client = opensearchpy.OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}],
    http_compress=True,
    http_auth=auth,
    use_ssl=False,
    verify_certs=False,

)

index_name = 'loggerheads'

# Add a document to the index.
document = {
  'timestamp': '2022-02-09 11:11:11.111',
  'message': 'some random ship'
}

response = client.index(
    index = index_name,
    body = document,
    refresh = True
)
```

I have previously configured my mapping like this:

```
PUT loggerheads
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The timestamp gets displayed wrong:
[image]
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

#### Edit

I sent a series of documents to opensearch. The observation is that any date in 2023 is being displayed as `2023-01-02`. Furthermore:

- 2022 -> `2022-01-03`
- 2021 -> `2021-01-04`
- 2020 -> `2019-12-30`
- 2019 -> `2018-12-31`
- 2018 -> `2018-01-01`
- 2017 -> `2017-01-02`
- 2016 -> `2016-01-04`
- 2015 -> `2014-12-29`
- 2014 -> `2013-12-30`
- 2013 -> `2012-12-31`
- 2012 -> `2012-01-02`
- 2011 -> `2011-01-03`
- 2010 -> `2010-01-04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem in the `format` with uppercase and lowercase. Please try the following.

```
PUT loggerheads
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#multiple-date-formats

Comment: This is absolutely great. Bit weird how that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Stack Management -> Advanced Settings. Change value in Date Format.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's already set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS`